# Instagram API authorization on secondary pages

Tags: php, api, instagram, access-token

I am using Cosenary Instagram-PHP-API (https://github.com/cosenary/Instagram-PHP-API) and have been able to successfully retrieve user media from user accounts. However, when I redirect clients to another php page (e.g. 'action.php'), I loose all the authentication and get the '400' error message saying that: The access_token provided is invalid.' I have tried passing authCode and access_token to the second page and used them for authentication but still couldn't retrieve data. How should I store and pass authentication to the second page? I am trying to delete comments and unfollow people on the second pages.

Here is the code I am using (from examples folder):

```
$instagram = new Instagram(array(
    'apiKey' => '####',
    'apiSecret' => '#####',
    'apiCallback' => '...../success.php'
));
// receive OAuth code parameter
$code = $_GET['code'];

// check whether the user has granted access
if (isset($code)) {
    // receive OAuth token object
    $data = $instagram->getOAuthToken($code);
    $username = $data->user->username;
    // store user access token
    $instagram->setAccessToken($data);

    // now you have access to all authenticated user methods
    $result = $instagram->getUserMedia();
} else {
    // check whether an error occurred
    if (isset($_GET['error'])) {
        echo 'An error occurred: ' . $_GET['error_description'];
    }
}
```